# Downloading files through puppeteer, need to maintain cookies/state

Tags: node.js, chromium, headless-browser, puppeteer

I'm currently downloading files using the `request` package using the following code:

```
request
    .get({
        url,
        headers: {
            Authorization: "base64"
        }
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.xlsx'))
```

This works nice and all when the authentication is a simple username/password or doesn't have one at all, but once 2 factor authentication comes in, it's going to be a real hassle since this method doesn't keep track of your cookies or login state (or however it's tracked).

So how would I get the buffer/data during puppeteer's run time then pipe it into another filestream (note I will need to do this recursively for several files).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can construct the cookies header from puppeteer like this:

```
  cookies = await page.cookies();
  cookie_str = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i+=1){
        a = cookies[i];
        cookie_str += a.name + "=" + a.value + ";";
  }
```

and then use `request` with a cookie header:

```
request.get({
        url: download_link,
        headers: {
            "cookie": cookie_str,
        }
    }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("ofname"))
```